# Change the C/C++ build command for my project

Tags: eclipse

I need to be able to change a projects build command in my Eclipse plugin. I have an Eclipse plugin that I need to have the build command for the current project changed whenever it is activated. I would like the plugin to do this rather than the user to have to manually change it.

Comment: Please provide more details, such as the name of the plugin.  I'm not sure whether you mean you are writing the plugin yourself, or if you are using it.  Also, welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: I am creating the plugin myself. And thank you for the welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question on my own. If you use ManagedBuildManager it allows you to modify the build command.

Here is sample code:

```
IConfiguration config = ManagedBuildManager.getBuildInfo(activeProject).getDefaultConfiguration();
config.setBuildCommand("test");
ManagedBuildManager.saveBuildInfo(activeProject, true);
```